# Cannot create new Firefox Webdriver Selenium Mac OS 10.9.5, Firefox 39.0

Tags: java, macos, firefox, selenium

I am trying to run selenium java 2.45.0. I have attempted to simply create a new Webdriver object in java:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

But fails with the following trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Error Message</TITLE>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<STYLE id=L_default_1>A {
    FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #005a80; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
}
A:hover {
    FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #0d3372; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
}
TD {
    FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
}
TD.titleBorder {
    BORDER-RIGHT: #955319 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #955319 1px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 8px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-LEFT: #955319 0px solid; COLOR: #955319; BORDER-BOTTOM: #955319 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma; HEIGHT: 35px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d2b87a; TEXT-ALIGN: left
}
TD.titleBorder_x {
    BORDER-RIGHT: #955319 0px solid; BORDER-TOP: #955319 1px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 8px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-LEFT: #955319 1px solid; COLOR: #978c79; BORDER-BOTTOM: #955319 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma; HEIGHT: 35px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d2b87a; TEXT-ALIGN: left
}
.TitleDescription {
    FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
}
SPAN.explain {
    FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #934225
}
SPAN.TryThings {
    FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #934225
}
.TryList {
    MARGIN-TOP: 5px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
}
.X {
    BORDER-RIGHT: #955319 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #955319 1px solid; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; BORDER-LEFT: #955319 1px solid; COLOR: #7b3807; BORDER-BOTTOM: #955319 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d1c2b4
}
.adminList {
    MARGIN-TOP: 2px
}
</STYLE>
<META content="MSHTML 6.00.2800.1170" name=GENERATOR></HEAD>
<BODY bgColor=#f3f3ed>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%">
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD class=titleborder_x width=30>
      <TABLE height=25 cellSpacing=2 cellPadding=0 width=25 bgColor=black>
        <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD class=x vAlign=center align=middle>X</TD>
        </TR>
        </TBODY>
      </TABLE>
    </TD>
    <TD class=titleBorder id=L_default_2>Network Access Message:<SPAN class=TitleDescription> The page cannot be displayed</SPAN> </TD>
  </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>

<TABLE id=spacer>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD height=10></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<TABLE width=400>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD noWrap width=25></TD>
    <TD width=400><SPAN class=explain><ID id=L_default_3><B>Explanation:</B></ID></SPAN><ID id=L_default_4> There is a problem with the page you are trying to reach and it cannot be displayed. </ID><BR><BR>
    <B><SPAN class=tryThings><ID id=L_default_5><B>Try the following:</B></ID></SPAN></B> 
      <UL class=TryList>
        <LI id=L_default_6><B>Refresh page:</B> Search for the page again by clicking the Refresh button. The timeout may have occurred due to Internet congestion.
<LI id=L_default_7><B>Check spelling:</B> Check that you typed the Web page address correctly. The address may have been mistyped.
<LI id=L_default_8><B>Access from a link:</B> If there is a link to the page you are looking for, try accessing the page from that link.

      </UL>
<ID id=L_default_9>If you are still not able to view the requested page, try contacting your administrator or Helpdesk.</ID> <BR><BR>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>

<TABLE id=spacer><TBODY><TR><TD height=15></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>

<TABLE width=400>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD noWrap width=25></TD>
    <TD width=400 id=L_default_10><B>Technical Information (for support personnel)</B> 
      <UL class=adminList>
        <LI id=L_default_11>Error Code: 502 Proxy Error. The ISA Server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). (12202)
<LI id=L_default_12>IP Address: 10.9.1.80
<LI id=L_default_13>Date: 15/07/2015 18:23:46
<LI id=L_default_14>Server: proxy02
<LI id=L_default_15>Source: proxy

      </UL>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
Command duration or timeout: 403 milliseconds
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this might be happening? I am using selenium 2.45.0, Mac OS 10.9.5, jdk 1.7.0_76, firefox 39.0. My firefox is installed to /Applications/Firefox.app

Thank you kindly,
Jason

Comment: As my remembering, FF39 should come with selenium 2.46. Have you tried to update your selenium package?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean FF39 comes bundle inside selenium, or the driver itself? Separately, I've attempted to use the 2.46.0 version of the selenium java with FF39 and still no joy!

Answer (score 0):

**Cannot create new Firefox Webdriver Selenium Mac OS 10.9.5, Firefox 39.0:**

Update Your firefox as well as selenium jar file to the latest one. It will work :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was seemingly fixed by adding        System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");

or setting a vm argument in JVM startup